# Is Holo theme broken in API Level 26?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I am figuring out a problem in my Spinners using the Holo theme.

Since I changed the target from API 14 to API 26 in the manifest, all the spinners that used a normal

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>( getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
```

show a black text on a black background. Other themes work good (i.e. I tested Holo.Light and DeviceDefault), but obviously they will change other stuff in the application, so they are not an option.

The theme is set in the Manifest

```
    <application
        android:name="myApp"
        ...
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"
        ...
        >
```

So, why the `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown` shows a black text on a black background since I changed the target API? do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also post the solution I am currently using. I am not really happy with it, so if you have better ideas, please tell me

My solution for the moment is to create a new theme for my app in styles.xml, that is

```
<style name="AppTheme_HoloFixed" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and in colors.xml it is obviously defined

```
<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Someone has a better solution?

Comment: And you need all this... just to set `android:textColor`? Looks to me like you're trying to shoot a mosquito with a bazooka.

Comment: I tried smaller stuff, like changing only `textPrimaryColor` or stuff like that, but it did not work...I needed `textColor`. I said I did not like my solution, but I do not have a better alternative at the moment...the other alternative that came to my mind was to create a new customized `simple_spinner_dropdown_item` layout and change the color only there....